# Question about percentage increase

Tags: percentages

If I have a car that is going at 2.0 speed and I put in special fuel that makes it have 30% reduced speed, what would the new speed be?

Comment: It would be $2\cdot 1.3=2.6$

Comment: Sorry I meant reduced speed not increased! What would it be?

Comment: $2\cdot0.7=1.4$

Answer (score 1):

$2-2×\frac{30}{100}=2-0.6=1.4 $ speed